# monitoring esxi using prometheus : getting error undefined: debug.ReadBuildInfo

Tags: go, prometheus, esxi, vcenter

i am trying monitor esxi via prometheus to grafana using https://github.com/devinotelecom/prometheus-vmware-exporter

when i am running

```
[root@admin01 prometheus-vmware-exporter]# docker build -t prometheus-vmware-exporter .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  157.7kB
Step 1/9 : FROM golang:1.11 as builder
 ---> 43a154fee764
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /src/github.com/devinotelecom/prometheus-vmware-exporter
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6b2aad4c7a43
Step 3/9 : COPY ./ /src/github.com/devinotelecom/prometheus-vmware-exporter
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2f5f1b155f7f
Step 4/9 : RUN go get -d -v
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a48d35b3d5e2
Step 5/9 : RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build
 ---> Running in 86199cee4fcb
# github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus
/go/src/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/build_info_collector.go:24:15: undefined: debug.ReadBuildInfo
The command '/bin/sh -c CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build' returned a non-zero code: 2
[root@admin01 prometheus-vmware-exporter]#
```

**Thanks for your help in Advanced**

Answer (score 0):

The minimal golang version in prometheus is 1.15, but in the Dockerfile it says 1.11

source : https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/main/go.mod

Try changing `golang:1.11` to `golang:1.15`++ in Dockerfile

Comment: Jazak Allah Rahmat Fathoni,

it works 

but again getting error in next command

#docker run -b --restart=always --name=prometheus-vmware-exporter --env=ESX_HOST abc.xyz.net --env=ESX_USERNAME root --env=ESX_PASSWORD NE$X1of1shn --env=ESX_LOG debug prometheus-vmware-exporter 

Unknown shorthand flag: 'b' in -b
See 'docker run --help'.

after removing -b 

Unable to find image 'abc.xyz.net:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for abc.xyz.net, repositry does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requeted acces to the resorce is denied.

Comment: Now the getting this err 

*"level=fatal msg="default host resolves to multiple instances, please specify"*